# Как передать значения переменной из функции в функцию которая в другом файле?

Tags: c#, unity3d

например есть два скрипта `PlayerController` и `PlayerHearth`
нужно передать значения переменой `PlayerStop` тип `bool` из функции `RestartLevel` какая в скрипте `PlayerHearth` в скрипт `PlayerController` в функцию `Update` как это можна сделать?

Comment: И давно у нас файл с кодом на C# стал называться `скриптом`? Скриптами зовутся коды написанные на интерпретируемом языке, на JavaScript например, а C# все же относится к компилируемым языкам. А в чём проблема вызова, разве методы не находятся в одном `namespace` ?

Comment: @Bulson, дело в том что тут идет речь о Unity3D что немного меняет взгляд на C#. Я о том что автор скорей всего прочитал мануал от разработчиков Unity и там как раз отельные файлы которые вешаются на объекты и называются скриптами.

Comment: @СергейИгнахин,  понял, спасибо, беру свои слова обратно :)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы можете в методе `Start` класса `PlayerController` создать экземпляр класса `PlayerHearth` и уже обращаться ко всем его публичным полям, свойствам и методам.

Если же вам необходимо чтоб экземпляр класса `PlayerHearth` создавался средой Unity3D. То вы можете объявить публичное поле внутри `PlayerController` типа `PlayerHearth` *(Данное поле придется создавать и в первом случае)* и непосредственно в редакторе **Unity** перетянуть один объект на другой, таким образом у вас из класса `PlayerController` будет доступ ко всем публичным полям, свойствам и методам класса `PlayerHearth` и соответственно вы получите доступ к полю `PlayerStop`.

**Дополнительно**

Есть еще альтернативный вариант сделать `PlayerHearth` **синглтоном** и обращаться уже напрямую к одному единственному экземпляру класса. Что в общем обычно является плохой идеей, так как вы не сможете реализовать работу нескольких персонажей без дополнительных манипуляций.

**P.S.** У вас на выбор есть множество вариантов реализации данного функционала. Более конкретные ответы сообщество может дать вам если вы более полно опишите, то чего вы хотите добиться.